# random.sample producing same output when iterated over inside function

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to write a poker hand evaluator with a monte carlo simulation.

When simulating game outcomes (e.g. dealing cards) inside a function using `random.sample` randomization works fine.

```
def simulate(hands, board):
    # create deck
    suits = ['d','s','c','h']
    ranks = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K']
    cards = []
    for r in ranks:
        for s in suits:
            cards.append(r+s)
    
    # shuffle deck
    deck = random.sample(cards,len(cards)) 
    # remove board and player cards from deck
    deck = list(filter(lambda x: x not in board, deck))
    for hand in hands:
          deck = list(filter(lambda x: x not in hand, deck))
    
    # deal turn and river
    while len(board) < 5:
        card = deck.pop(0)
        board.append(card)
    return board
```

```
for i in range(2):
    outcome = simulate([['Ah', 'Ac'], ['7s', '6s']], ['2d', '5s', '8s'])
    print(outcome)
Output:
['2d', '5s', '8s', '9s', 'Jc']
['2d', '5s', '8s', '4s', '3s']
```

If I run this inside a for loop it works fine but
once I put this into another function randomization fails and I keep getting the same result.

```
def monte_carlo(hands, board, samples=5):
    for i in range(samples):
        outcome = simulate(hands, board)
        print(outcome)

monte_carlo([['Ah', 'Ac'], ['7s', '6s']], ['2d', '5s', '8s'])

Output:
Board  ['2d', '5s', '8s', '2c', '4d']
None
Board  ['2d', '5s', '8s', '2c', '4d']
None
Board  ['2d', '5s', '8s', '2c', '4d']
None
Board  ['2d', '5s', '8s', '2c', '4d']
None
Board  ['2d', '5s', '8s', '2c', '4d']
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: The `board` passed to `simulate` during each loop in the function is the same list object. Please refer to [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment) for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky little piece around the `list` type and the fact it's mutable. If you change this line of code: `outcome = simulate(hands, board)` to `outcome = simulate(hands, [b for b in board])` you'll get the desired result.

The `[b for b in board]` just creates a new list which has the same elements as `board`. Importantly, it is a different list behind the scenes in python. New memory is associated with it. If you don't do this, the `board` that is being used in each iteration of the loop is a reference to the exact same list. To visualise it, add this debug into the code:

```
def monte_carlo(hands, board, samples=5):
    print("NOW MY BOARD HAS VALUE: ", board)
    for i in range(samples):
        outcome = simulate(hands, board)
        print(outcome)
```

You'll see that that debug shows the value of `board` changing in time, even though the `board` that's being printed is outside the `simulate` function. Because lists are mutable, all references to the list point to the exact same memory. It's not like each time you run `simulate(hands, board)` you're sending in a brand new version of `board`, exactly as it was when you called `monte_carlo(hands, board)`. No, you're sending in the exact same list. And because inside `simulate` you're changing the list (i.e. adding elements), those changes also exist in the `monte_carlo` method's reference to `board`.

Comment: `[b for b in board]` is a rather heavyweight method for making a shallow copy of a list, as it involves a Python iteration over each element.  `board.copy()` or `board[:]` would be simpler ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: Agreed! Honestly, didn't think of it, haha.